# How to extract data from a PDF and store in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PDF document that contains data that I would like to extract and store in a MySQL database. Could anyone give me some guidance or perhaps sample PHP code?

Comment: Please be please be more specific.

Comment: YOu want to extract data from a PDF and insert into a MySQL table?

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at an edit. I think I grep the root question.

Answer (score 1):

There's some [basic code here for performing text extraction](http://community.livejournal.com/php/295413.html) from a PDF. Might work for you. For commercial libraries, check out [pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/pdflib/) which I believe can do similar extraction.

Once you have the data, it's up to you to massage that into MySQL INSERT statements to create your database.

Answer (score 0):

I often use the FPDF library to create PDF documents via a PHP script. Plenty of examples and documentation here: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: But the OP doesn't want to generate PDFs, he wants to read them.

Comment: okay. this was not obvious from the first version of the post!

Answer (score 0):

What do you wanna do ?

If you want to store the PDF in a MySQL database, i recommand you to store the pdf in a directory and the path to the pdf in the mysql database.
Or you can store `file_get_contents($pathToThePDF)` in the db but I don't think it's a good idea.

If you want to create with PHP a PDF with data from a MySQL db, i also use fpdf (like rascher) to do that and it works well + there are many example on the website.

Comment: Okay thanks EBGreen, I think schatzie should take a look at Zend_PDF, maybe it could do that kind of thing since it's able to open a pdf and then modify it.